# Is there a way to check if a relationship is empty?

Tags: swift, core-data

Currently I have a FetchedResults List which I want to filter. Only objects which have objects on the other side of the relationship should be in the filtered List.

```
let filteredList = fetchedList.filter { $0.name == SelectedItem.name && $0.RELATIONSHIP != nil}
```

However this does not work how I intended it to do.
If I print out

```
print(SelectedItem.RELATIONSHIP)
```

I get this:

```
...
RELATIONSHIP =     (
    );
}) with objects {(
)})
```

So is there any command maybe like:

```
SelectedItem.RELATIONSHIP.isEmpty
```

Thanks

Comment: If I try this command, I get an error code saying that the other entity has no member "isEmpty"

Comment: If I ```print(SelectedItem.RELATIONSHIP == nil)``` I always get false

Comment: If your relationship is a to-one then `== nil` should work, if it is a to-many then try `SelectedItem.RELATIONSHIP.count == 0`

Comment: It is a to-many and trying the last code I get the same error saying that the entity has no member .count

Comment: Well I can do that (`.count`) with my core data objects so I can't help you any more.

Comment: Interesting. Did you specify any specific in the data model inspector for this relationship?